# Messages sent from the background script not being received by the content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Trying to send a message from the backgroung script to the content script but the message is not received.

Been googling for hours but nothing seems to work.

Content script code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("background.js got a message")
        console.log(request); // tried with .txt
        console.log(sender);
    }
);
```

Backgroung script code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if(changeInfo.url != null){
        if (changeInfo.url.includes('csfd.cz')) {
            console.log("ČSFD detected: " + changeInfo.url);
            getNetflixInfo();
        }
    }
});

function getInfo() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://www.randomurl.com");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var altNameStr = "",
            s = xhr.responseText,
            re = /data-title="title"><[^<]+>([^<]+)</gmi,
            item;

        while (item = re.exec(s)) {
            //arr.push(item[1]);
            altNameStr += '|' + item[1];
        }
        console.log(altNameStr);

        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"});
        });

      }
      else {
          alert('XHR status = ' + xhr.status)
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue. The background script runs in a separate hidden background page which is initialized either at browser start (or when the extension is reloaded) for persistent scripts and whenever it's resumed for non-persistent scripts. Whereas the content script runs when a web page is loaded in the tab, which is totally unrelated to the background script. You probably need to change the workflow depending on what the extension does exactly. The usual fix is to make the content script initiate the communication.

Comment: So something like: send a message from the content script to the background script and have the background script respond with a reply? I will try that when I get back from work.

Comment: Yep, and don't forget `return true` if you call sendResponse inside XHR or other chrome.* callback. Example: [Not getting response Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/37459650)

Comment: @wOxxOm my mind is fried, but yea, it worked... thanks a bunch